# How to use Generic Parameters for dynamic where clause chosen by user via drop down parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hello SSRS wizards of the internet,

I did not know how to phrase it in the title but hopefully the explanation below does:

I have a parameter (@search_Criteria) with available values: ('product', 'customer id', 'account #')

The user can choose only one of these and then input values into 5 text fields to pass in some parameters. The query will then run the where clause corresponding to what value in @search_Criteria they chose.

E.g: User wants to retrieve a report on 2 products spoons, and forks.

The user chooses @search_Critera = 'product'

and inputs in 2 of the five parameters:

@Param1 = 'Spoons'
@Param2 = 'Forks'

the rest are default to Null

Then a query for the ssrs report's dataset (pseudo query for now as it does not run but I placed it for what I am trying to do) runs in the background

```
Select * 
From Table

Case when @search_Criteria = 'Products' then (Where Table.Products in (@Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5))
Else @search_Criteria = 'Customer id' then (Where Table.[Customer id] in (@Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5))
```

Comment: As you mentioned in the title of the issue you have to use dynamic sql.

Comment: Have you considered consolidating these parameters into one multi-value product parameter? In other words, the first parameter would be the search type and then the second parameter would be a multi-value dropdown with the options for that type. Is there a reason you don't want it designed this way? I think it would be easier to use and to implement.

Comment: @StevenWhite That is out of my control, If I would have a choice in the design I would do it that way, but apparently this way is more "intuitive"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your specifications, the conditions should be structured like this:

```
Select * 
From Table

WHERE (@search_Criteria = 'Products' AND Table.Products in (@Param1, @Param2, ...))
OR (@search_Criteria = 'CustomerId' AND Table.CustomerId in (@Param1, @Param2, ...)) 
OR (@search_Criteria = 'Account#' AND Table.AccountNo in (@Param1, @Param2, ...))
```

Be aware of data types. These are all being passed as strings from the report so you may have to convert the column to a string for comparison. So something like 
    `CAST(Table.AccountNo as varchar(20))`

Comment: ofcourse...I was almost there. I don't know why I didn't think of the extra step. Thanks Steven White!